# Symfony 4 FosUserBundle controller decoration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I am decorating a base class SecurityController from FosUserBundle with:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
   public function renderLogin(array $data)
   {

    $template = sprintf('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.%s', $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'));

. . .
```

and in my Services.yaml:

```
App\Controller\SecurityController:
    decorates: fos_user.security.controller
```

The issue is that I receive the error:

```
The parameter "fos_user.template.engine" must be defined.
```

related to the line in renderLogin method:

```php
$template = sprintf('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.%s', $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'));
```

How can I get this missing parameter? The above line is from Symfony2 and now I using it in Symfony4.

Should I inject `fos_user.template.engine` or there is another syntax to get it inside the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error means that the `fos_user.template.engine` parameter is not defined.

This parameter was defined on older versions of FOS_User, but no more, and it's not needed. You could define it in your configuration files as `twig`, but better to use the approach that current `FOS_User` uses.

If you check the `renderLogin()` method of [SecurityController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php), the class you are decorating, you'll find that it's like this:

```php
protected function renderLogin(array $data)
{
    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Security/login.html.twig', $data);
}
```

Base your extended method on this one, and you can get rid of the `$template = sprintf() ...` line altogether.

E.g.:

```php
protected function renderLogin(array $data) {
    $data['foo'] = "bar";
    // do whatever else you need to do

    return parent::renderLogin($data);
}
```